# Request to existed table' value

Tags: sql

There are two table

1st one(Empl):

- Name
- Id

2nd one (Phone):

- Phone
- id_emp

Each employe has got one two or three pnones or does not have anything

The task is to get all employes with phones

Am I correct ?

```
SELECT Empl.Name, Empl.id, phone.phone
FROM Empl
LEFT JOIN phone
ON empl.Id=phone.id_emp
where phone.phone >= 1
ORDER BY Empl.Name, Empl.Id;
```

Comment: No.  If you want all employees with phones, you can just use an `inner join` and dispense with the `where` clause.

Comment: You tell us if you're correct. When you execute that query, do you get the results you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get records that exists in both tables, you can use `INNER JOIN`. That will return only those employees that have at least one phone.

`INNER JOIN` returns rows from both sides that meet the join condition and only those rows. `LEFT JOIN` you used will return also those rows from `Empl` table that don't have any phones (don't match the join condition `empl.Id=phone.id_emp`).

```
SELECT Empl.Name, Empl.id, phone.phone
FROM Empl
INNER JOIN phone
ON empl.Id=phone.id_emp
ORDER BY Empl.Name, Empl.Id;
```